# material radio button not supported in API 16

Tags: android, radio-button, material-design

I have this XML file for display the radio button and getting crashed on opening this file. I have this XML code below:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/darkblue"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Schedule"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow_icon_battery_saver_app"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@color/lightblue"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="23:00"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton"
                android:id="@+id/textView36" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView36"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView36"
                android:id="@+id/textView37" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="07:30"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView36"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView37"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView37"
                android:id="@+id/textView38" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Long-life"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/textView39"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView38"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editsche"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editsche" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrowicon"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView39"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:id="@+id/editsche" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/darkblue"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="+ Add Schedule"
                android:id="@+id/addschdedule"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners"
                android:shadowColor="@color/buttonshadow"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="47dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have this XMl file.Its not supported in API below 20 I am getting error below .

FATAL EXCEPTION: `main                                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class android.widget.RadioButton`

Comment: try to clean and re-build the project

Comment: I have tried this still getting same error.

Comment: show your full xml code

Comment: I have edited the code

Comment: use this library version (v7:23.4.0) instead of (v7:24.0.0)

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'   
}